# sessionfactory with multithread

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

> Is it possible to create mini session factory with some classes on one
>   thread and then and create full session factory on a second thread?
>
> i want to speed up initialization of sessionfactory
>
> Can you show how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to speed up startup is to serialize the configuration object which takes most of the startuptime for building and validating, [see here](http://entron.wordpress.com/2010/01/06/optimizing-application-startup-time-with-fluent-nhibernate-and-unhaddins/).

The code to implement your aproach:

```
var minisessionfactory = Fluently.Configure()
    .DataBase(SomeConfiguration.Standard....)
    // only add the relevant mappings
    .Mapping(m => m.FluentMappings.Add<AMap>().Add<BMap>()...)
    .BuildSessionfactory();

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
{
    RealSessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
        .DataBase(SomeConfiguration.Standard....)
        // only add the relevant mappings
        .Mapping(m => ...)
        .BuildSessionfactory();
    SessionFactoryReady = true;
});

// do some Stuff with minisessionfactory
```

Update:

Did you measured where the time is really spent: Building the Configuration or build the Factory?

If its building the factory, enable full logging to see if there are some steps which take long and could be disabled.

UpdateUpdate: simple implementations

```
ISession GetSession()
{
    while (!SessionFactoryReady) Thread.Sleep(1000);
    return RealSessionFactory.OpenSession();
}

// or

ISessionFactory SessionFactory
{
    get
    {
        while (!SessionFactoryReady) Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return RealSessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already done the serialization of configuration.Is it not possible to use the minisessionfactory again to create the full sessionfactory. I think you are creating two separate sessionfactory.

Comment: you can reuse the configuration but not the sessionfactory no.

Comment: how to check which session factory to use. i mean minisession factory is used in the beginning for certain classes. there should be a mechanism to check whether the realsessionfactory is ready or not to be used by others

Comment: how can i keep method calling the real session factory into wait. could you please show it by code.

Comment: where I am having problem is that i have a single method to create session factory. suppose i create mini sessionfactory for few entities. so initially the method return minisession as the creation of full session is not yet finished as it is running on separate thread. do i need to check for condition that minisession is only for certain entities and not for other enitities. how do i deal with this situation

Comment: the minifactory is only meant to deal with starting activities like license validation, user validation and so on and should be explicitly using the minifactory instead the real one. If it's really that slow to create the full factory then you really have a problem there. On my mediocre dev mashine it takes 2-3 seconds to build up a sessionfactory and connection with 50+ Entities mapped with fluentNhibernate and lots of nested components. I would strongly advice to measure where the time is spent while building the main factory

Comment: ok you mean to say mini sessionfactory should be explicitly called for activities like user validation.ok i got it. my last question is suppose a method called getcompany() want to access fullsessionfactory which is not yet ready then how do i make getcompany wait for it. thank you very much for ur help

Comment: see code i already posted, a simple while with sleep in the getter is enough

Comment: My thread never returns back. what could be the problem. i am working on wpf.

Comment: the threads never returns back when it hits buildsessionfactory.

Comment: better ask it as another question and post some code. it's hard to diagnose without seeing the code

Comment: I have posted another question with some code. Can you please have a look